# Mule project migration from SOAP to JSON

Tags: json, wsdl, mule

I would like to understand whether we really have any tool to convert the WSDL to RAML for migrating the project from SOAP to JSON.

Share with me the tool if we have any.

Comment: You mean to convert from SOAP to a REST API? JSON is not really a comparable standard to SOAP. And note that RAML allows for XML payloads too.

Answer (score 0):

There maybe some tools that perform a translation between WSDL and RAML but the standards are significantly different and any automated translations can be partial only. You are probably going to need to complete manually the translation. You might get better results by starting a RAML version from scratch without the artifacts left by a tool.